# Getting error when I send email using Postal MVC and SendAsync()

Tags: c#, email, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-4, postal

I'm trying to send an email using [Postal MVC](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) in my MVC controller. I want to send the email asynchronously and don't want to wait for the email to be sent before I return the View.

Here is the code that I'm trying to use.

```
        try
        {
            dynamic email = new Email("TestEmail");  //I have an Email View by this name
            email.To = "myemailaddress@domain.com";
            email.From = "recipientsaddress@domain.com";
            email.SendAsync();                      //email.Send() works fine
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
```

But I get this error "Failure sending mail."

Inner Exception System.InvalidOperationException:An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time.Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle.If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. at System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.OperationStarted() at System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperation.CreateOperation(Object userSuppliedState,SynchronizationContext syncContext) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendAsync(MailMessage message,Object userToken)

If I replace the SendAsync() with Send() it works fine.

For completeness sake, this what my mailSettings look like in my Web.Config

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="smtp.myisp.com" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Something seems to be wrong with sending the email asynchronously. Has anyone else come up with this problem and have a solution?

Or should I use another mailer like [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide)?

Please don't suggest that I should not send the email asynchronously. I want the response of my site to be fast and I find connecting to an email server to send an email during a sign up process to be a little non-responsive.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the Exception type rather than just the message text?

Comment: Post the Inner Exception messgae please. And maybe the Stack Trace... Something useful.

Comment: Looking at the Postal code, this may not actually work unless the e-mail sends really fast, it looks like the mailMessage may be being disposed before the async message can send... i just may not work.  My suggestion would be to use the parsers from Postal and call the SmtpClient directly..

Comment: You could test to see if there is a dispose problem by adding `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)` to the end of the method.

Comment: InnerException=System.InvalidOperationException:An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time.Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle.If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>.at System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.OperationStarted() at System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperation.CreateOperation(Object userSuppliedState,SynchronizationContext syncContext) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendAsync(MailMessage message,Object userToken)

Comment: @Martin: I tried putting that sleep line right after the SendAsync() line and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: This is the Exception's StackTrace=at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendAsync(MailMessage message, Object userToken) at Postal.EmailService.SendAsync(Email email) at Postal.Email.SendAsync() at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object ) at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid1[T0](CallSite site, T0 arg0) at Website.Models.SignUpProcess.SendConfirmationCodeEmail(SignUpForm SignUpFormData, String GeneratedEmailConfirmationCode, ModelStateDictionary SignupFormModelState) in c:\...\SignUpProcess.cs:line 90.      
Line 90 is the statement to email.SendAsync();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that Postal MVC is not compatible with MVC4's new Async mechanism.  Until the developers of Postal MVC make it compatible you have 2 options, downgrade to MVC3, or force the old MVC3 functionality in your application.

To revert to the old functionality in MVC4, you can apply the following setting in your web.config:

```
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="false" />
```

Be wary of just doing this though, there may be implications within your site from doing this.  I suggest that you research the implications.

Comment: That key does not exist in my web.config file.

Comment: have you tried adding it, and changing the value to false true.  I'm not sure what the setting does, but it's worth trying.  Also, can you confirm whether it's .NET 4.5/MVC4 or whether it's MVC3 (try switching to MVC3 to see if makes a difference).

Comment: Thank you Martin. I put that key into my web.config under the <appSettings> and set it to "false" and it worked fine. Now my page loads approximately 2 seconds faster after multiple tests.

Comment: @Martin just out of curiosity, shouldn't the action method be declared as `public async Task<ActionResult> actionName(...)` and then use `await Task.Run(() => email.SendAsync());` ??

I had the same problem and found this solution and it works.

Comment: this may work, I've no idea to be honest... pop it as answer and maybe Freejelly can try it...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the [latest version](https://github.com/andrewdavey/postal) of Postal. They have included a [unit test of sending Async](https://github.com/andrewdavey/postal/blob/master/src/Postal.Tests/EmailServiceTests.cs) which should help you understand what's wrong.  This suggests it is not a problem with Postal.

The test also suggests that you might have to use a `SpecifiedPickupDirectory`

Comment: I couldn't get that unit test to compile. He is using some libraries and references which I don't have access to like Moq and Xunit. Is there a simpler example to send the email using Async? Thanks.